# @Autowired component is not available

Tags: java, spring

My class is an sftp poller.  It implements DirectoryListener and implements the fileAdded method to monitor when new events are added to an sftp directory.  Code looks like

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @Slf4j
    public class SftpBridge implements DirectoryListener, IoErrorListener, InitialContentListener {
        @Autowired
        private SftpBridgeConfig config;

        @Autowired
        public SftpDirectory sftpDirectory;

        public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(SftpBridge.class, args);
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {
            LOG.info("Initializing...");

            initialize();

            LOG.info("Initialized!");
        }

        private void initialize() {
            pollSftp();
        }

public void pollSftp() {
    try {
        while (true) {

            LOG.info("monitoring directory: " + "/");
            PolledDirectory polledDirectory = sftpDirectory;

            DirectoryPoller dp = DirectoryPoller.newBuilder()
                    .addPolledDirectory(polledDirectory)
                    .addListener(new SftpBridge())
                    // other settings

                    //remove this later
                    .enableFileAddedEventsForInitialContent() // optional (disabled by default). FileAddedEvents fired for directories initial content.

                    //TODO: enable later for subdirectory polling
                    //.enableParallelPollingOfDirectories() // optional (disabled by default).

                    .setDefaultFileFilter(new RegexFileFilter(".*csv")) // optional. Only consider files ending with "xml".
                    .setThreadName("sftp-poller") // sets the name of the the polling thread
                    .setPollingInterval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .start();

            TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(2);

            dp.stop();

        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error monitoring ftp host", e);
    }
}
```

Since pollSftp() is called by initialize() during Spring boot application init, it is able to see the @Autowired component SftpBridgeConfig config.

My problem is that my class implements DirectoryListener, I have to override the fileAdded event to take some action when a new ftp file is added.

```
    @Override
public void fileAdded(FileAddedEvent event) {
    LOG.info("Added: " + event.getFileElement());
//implementing DirectoryListener
//@Autowired component config is null here as it is called from a polling thread

}
```

in the fileAdded(FileAddedEvent event) method, my @Autowired component config is null, because this method is not called during Spring boot init.  What is the best way to structure the code so that the @Autowired component config is available when fileAdded() is called by an sftp directory polling thread?

Thanks for any advice.

Edit: @Andreas - I've filled out my pollSftp() method which adds the class as a DirectoryListener.  Thanks

Comment: Where is the class used as a `DirectoryListener`? I assume it's given to some sftp API in the `pollSftp()` method. Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an annotaion in SftpBridgeConfig? 
cf. @Service @Component

if configuration class, need to register @Bean in the spring context.
cf. @Bean(name="") or @Bean

ex) message source configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfiguration { 

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
      // statements
    }
}
```

Comment: SftpBridgeConfig has an annotation `@Configuration`.  Should I add `@Bean` to it as well?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  When ```@Override
public void fileAdded(FileAddedEvent event)``` is called from an api call, all of my `@Autowired` components are null.  My SftpBridgeConfig class looks like `@Configuration public class SftpBridgeConfig {     @Bean
    public SftpDirectory sftpDirectory() {
        return new SftpDirectory(getSftpHost(), getSftpWorkingDirectory(), getSftpUser(), getSftpPassword());
    }` both config and sftpDirectory are null.